# List all posts from past week grouped by sub-category

Tags: query, get-posts

On a category specific template, I want to list all the posts from the last 7 seven days for that single single category and group them by subcategory.

This is the code I have so far, which lists the posts by category, but doesn't limit it to the past week:

```
<?php
$categories =  get_categories( 'child_of=83' );  
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
        echo '<h3>' . $category -> name . '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( get_posts( 'cat=' . $category -> term_id ) as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $post -> ID ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';   
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

**How can I show only published posts dated within the past 7 days, including today?**

I thought I would try to use the WP_Query date_query parameter to restrict the list with something like this, but can't figure out how to make this work:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => '1 week ago',
        'before' => 'tomorrow',
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
);
```

Comment: On which page are you doing this. Got a feeling that the custom query is unnecessary

Comment: check this tutorial https://tommcfarlin.com/get-posts-from-last-week/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `WP_Query` for this one:

```
$categories =  get_categories( 'child_of=83' );  
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<h3>' . $category -> name . '</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';

    // create a WP_Query that retreives all posts from the specified
    // category which is older then 1 week
    $args = array(
      'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
      'date_query' => array(
         array(
          'column' => 'post_date',
          'after' => '1 week ago'
         )
       ),
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // check so there is some posts in the resultset
    if($query->have_posts()) {
      // loop through the result
      while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        // output data here
      }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: This code generated the list of subcategories, but there were two problems: 1) it returned the same lists of posts under each sub-category heading, and 2) it did not limit the posts to only published posts, allowing scheduled posts to be listed too.

Comment: That seems very strange, have you tried to reset the query after `while()` loop using: `wp_reset_postdata();` I don't have time right now, but will test this for myself tomorrow and update my answer.

Comment: wp_reset_postdata(); doesn't change the output.

Comment: @draney - Oh, I found one error, you should of course use `$category->cat_ID` instead of `$category->ID`, updated my answer.